# How do I apply text effects like this in "The Three Evils"

Tags: formatting, html, text-formatting

I know there's an online utility that does it but I can't seem to find it. All my Googling has been in vain.

The T̜͓̞̤͎ͦ́ͤ̓̄̚ḣ͖͙̘ͦͯ̾re͗̈́e ̙̥̘̙͉̺̜̐ͧ̍E͍̲̜͈͊v̹͙̝̗ils is the only example I could find of the text effect I'm looking for.

Not looking for the utility specifically, but what the effect is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called 'Zalgo' on Stack Exchange, and how it works can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844/4751173).

It makes use of so-called ['combining characters'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) in Unicode. A combining character basically says 'I'm a normal character, except that you must render me above/below/inside the base character.

[Here](http://www.zalgotextgenerator.com/unicode) is a list of combining characters; you can just copy them from there.

**Note** that the use of Zalgo is discouraged on more serious websites (except when demonstrating [the limits of regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)). That might explain the downvotes on this question.